# Azure AD Authentication with 2FA

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, webapi, multi-factor-authentication

I have Authentication service which authenticate users based on the settings that they have configure via web portal. One of the authentication method that I have provided is Authentication via Azure AD. Below is my code which is called by my service.

```
     public async Task<string> Create(AzureAdTokenConfig config, string userName, string password)
 {
                    try
                    {
                        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(new PublicClientApplicationOptions()
                        {
                            ClientId = config.ClientId,
                            TenantId = config.TenantId,
                            AadAuthorityAudience = config.AadAuthorityAudience.ToEnum<AadAuthorityAudience>().Value,
                            AzureCloudInstance = config.AzureCloudInstance.ToEnum<AzureCloudInstance>().Value,
                        }).Build();
        
                        var result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, userName, GetSecureString(password)).ExecuteAsync();
                        return result.AccessToken;
                    }
                    catch (MsalException msalException) when (_errorCodes.Contains(msalException.ErrorCode))
                    {
                        throw new InfrastructureException(msalException.ErrorCode, msalException.Message, msalException);
                    }
}
```

The access token that I get from this code is used in maintaining session of user, so basically what I do is to verify the user name and password that is sent by user in login request via Azure AD and uses that token to maintain session separately.
It was working fine till last December, Now I am getting error

**due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access**

I googled the error, but was unable to find the solution that suits my requirement. What I require is to get access token and use it in my session. Is there a way where I can skip redirecting the user to another page, as this is done silently without much user interaction. An in depth solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The user/password flow is considered [unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password?tabs=dotnet#this-flow-isnt-recommended). The admin of your Azure tenant might have turned it off entirely or restricted the ip adresses of clients who may use that flow. In the latter case you might get your admin to add new ip adresses.

In the long run it probably would be better to switch over to a safe flow like the [device flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-device-code-flow?tabs=dotnet) or whatever suits your requirements.