# 2FA with user credentials and Microsoft Authenticator notifies on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, two-factor-authentication

I want to integrate 2FA in my application, already registered on Azure AD.
The authentication flow requires the user to enter a username and password and immediately after clicking on Login, he must receive a notification on his Microsoft Authenticator app to confirm or decline the access.
In my Java code, I used PublicClientApplication (with my client id and tenant) and UserNamePasswordParameters (with scopes, username and password).
When I try to acquire the token, passing my UsernamePasswordParameters to my PublicClientApplication I get this exception:

> "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your
> administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use
> multi-factor authentication to access ''.

I've already search some questions on this site, but they are not decisive for my case:

["Azure-ad-authentication-with-2fa"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76260298/azure-ad-authentication-with-2fa)

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: ROPC /Username-Password flow doesn't support MFA enabled accounts. If you are passing user with MFA enabled to login to the application, it will be blocked. Refer [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

I **enabled the user with MFA** like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to generate the access token using **ROPC flow** via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:password
username:ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:****
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

And I got the **error** like below:

[image]

When **I tried with the user with no MFA enabled, the access token generated** successfully:

[image]

Hence, **to resolve the issue**, make use of other interactive flows such as Authorization Code flow or Implicit flow.

I used the below endpoint to **authorize** the users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

The **code** got generated successfully like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:-ClientSecret
```

[image]

**References:**

[Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide?tabs=SpringCloudAzure4x)

[Azure AD Integration in Spring Boot Application | by Pradeep Maiya](https://medium.com/version-1/azure-ad-integration-in-spring-boot-application-81d66ffd4739)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the user trying to login to see a notification on his Microsoft Authenticator app to confirm login.  If I try to integrate other authentication flows, like the one you illustrated, the user who tries to login will never receive the login confirmation notification on Microsoft Authentication.

Comment: If you want to use ROPC Flow then it doesn't support MFA.

Comment: Could you tell me with which flow the user can receive the notification on his Microsoft Authenticator app every time he will try to login on my application?

Comment: Can you try implementing Authorization code flow and check.

Comment: Hi, I test a call with implicit code flow and works. It send me my redirect with code (token). But how can I integrate all this on my Java code? Since I would like the user to enter their credentials on my app and not go to the Microsoft login site, should I use webclient to make the call? But at that point, before reaching the last response with redirect uri + token, I would have some redirect uris in which to insert the username and password. Can Webclient be the solution or should I use something else? Do you have a concrete example in Java?